# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch with CORS disabled

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, cors

I have a problem with CORS. I tried so many things to try and solve it, I looked up online to find a way to fix my problem but nothing worked. I put some line in comments so you can see the places where I tried to put my code for CORS. I tried different combinations but it did not make any difference. I still get te same error: "Access to fetch at 'url' from origin 'https://localhost:7142' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

I hope someone will be able to help me.

ASP.NET Backend

```
using CounselingTree.Data;
using CounselingTree.Logic;
using CounselingTree.Repository;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var azureAdOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CounselingDbConnection");

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<PersonValidator>();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<PersonContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICounselingTreeRepository, CounselingTreeRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPersonLogic, PersonLogic>();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(setupAction =>
{
    setupAction.SwaggerDoc("apidocs", new()
    {
        Title = "Counseling tree Api",
        Version = "1",
        Description = "The counseling tree Api documentation description"
        
    });
    setupAction.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("AzureAuthorization"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("AzureToken"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {
                        "APIAccess",
                        "Reads the Api's"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    setupAction.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "oauth2"
                },
        }, new[] {azureAdOptions["ApiScope"]}
    } 
    });
});


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));


builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()));


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
    options.AddPolicy("PeopleManager", policy => policy.RequireRole("PeopleManager"));
});

/*builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7142/")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod());
});*/

//==========================================================================================

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var ctx = services.GetRequiredService<PersonContext>();
    /*ctx.Database.Migrate();

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        ctx.SeedInitialData();
    }*/
}



// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(setupAction =>
{
    setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/apidocs/swagger.json",
        "Counseling tree Api");
    setupAction.OAuthClientId("AzureClientId");
    setupAction.OAuthClientSecret("AzureClientSecret");
    setupAction.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

//app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Blazor client frontend

```
using BlazorApp1.Client;
using BlazorApp1.Client.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");


builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IPersonDataService, PersonDataService>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7006/"));

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("APIAccess");
});

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: [With endpoint routing, the CORS middleware must be configured to execute between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware)

Comment: You should read the official doc, the correct order should like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUsjK.png). If the issue still can't be fixed, please provide  a minimal reproducible example, so that we can help you as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @JasonPan thank you for you answer. I did as you asked but it still didn't solve the problem. Also, I'd love to share a minimal reproducible example with you but I can't because my code uses azure cloud a lot, without it the project can't run at all. But still I added code from my blazor client frontend. Maybe it will be useful